# Telebot Python получение сообщения

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Как сделать задержку в боте, допустим пользователь должен ввести какой то определенный текст и после этого он отправится в конфу админов? Тобишь система заявки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не особо понятно о какой задержке идёт речь, но вот пример:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите текст заявки')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, create_request)


def create_request(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ваша заявка принята')
    bot.forward_message(123, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(123, '{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}'.format(message.text, message.chat.id, message.from_user.first_name,
                                                       message.from_user.last_name, message.from_user.username))
```

- `forward_message` пересылает сообщения от пользователя (которое он отправил боту) в нужный чат
- `send_message` отправляет в нужный чат: текст сообщения, id имя, фамилию, ник пользователя
- `123` - id куда отправлять\пересылать сообщение
- *если нужно в группу - id пишется с минусом\тире (прим. -123). так же бот должен быть в группе и\или иметь права на отправку сообщений в группу*