# Как реализовать телеграм бота который принимает заявки и отправляет на телеграм канал?

Tags: python, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Здравствуйте у меня есть два вопроса

**1.** Как реализовать телеграм бота на языке программировании python с библиотекой `pyTelegramBotAPI`, нет я не прошу написать готовый код я просто не могу реализовать это в голове . Можете пожалуйста подсказать инструкцию. Этот бот принимает заявки у пользователей.И отправляет их в группу телеграм канал.
Например: есть группа `add hot` там 100 подписчиков, подписчики не могут отправлять сообщения, только видеть. Так вот, нужен мне еще один бот через него другие пользователи могли отправлять заявку по типу разместить рекламу на канале `add hot`, и вот пользователь заполняет свою рекламу. И нажимает отправить когда он нажал его заявка на размещения на канал `add hot` отправлена. И в канал приходит реклама который пользователь ввел в боте. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

**2.** Второй вопрос: Как мне взять id  моего телеграм канала? Я  когда в коде пишу `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'текст')` сообщение отправляется пользователю который пишет со своего  id , а мне нужно поменять на id моего канала чтобы сообщения приходили туда .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Отправка сообщения на канал с помощью бота](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138301/234134)

чтобы отправлять ботом сообщения в канал бот должен быть участником канала и иметь разрешение на публикацию сообщений.

так же вам нужно знать id канала, получить его можно:

```
import logging
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

- добавьте бота в канал
- назначьте его администратором
- отправьте в канал сообщение, например `/start`

в консоли вы должны увидеть примерно следующее:

> 2020-05-04 20:57:03,847 (apihelper.py:55 PollingThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":661653078,\n"channel_post":{"message_id":4276,"chat":{"id":-100...413,"title":"%name channel%","type":"channel"},"date":1588615023,"text":"/start","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"type":"bot_command"}]}}]}''"

где `id: -100...413` и есть id канала

[Telebot Python получение сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153340/234134)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите текст заявки')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, create_request)


def create_request(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ваша заявка принята')
    bot.forward_message(123, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(123, '{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}'.format(message.text, message.chat.id, message.from_user.first_name,
                                                       message.from_user.last_name, message.from_user.username))
```

- `forward_message` пересылает сообщения от пользователя (которое он отправил боту) в нужный чат (в сообщении будет "переслано от...")
- `send_message` отправляет в нужный чат: текст сообщения, id имя, фамилию, ник пользователя (в сообщении будут те поля которые указаны)
- `123` - id куда отправлять\пересылать сообщение
- *если нужно в группу - id пишется с минусом\тире (прим. -123). так же бот должен быть в группе и\или иметь права на отправку сообщений в группу*

Comment: а на aiogram как?
просто делаю бота на премиум канал)
Поможешь мне пожалуйста)

Comment: Используя методы aiogram согласно документации. https://docs.aiogram.dev/ru/latest/api/methods/forward_message.html#usage