# pytelegrambotapi: Помогите сделать send in group

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет. Я делаю бота, в которого люди должны будут отправлять видео. Я создал группу (чат), куда добавил бота, дабы он пересылал мне все сообщения от пользователей в эту группу. Но увы, я не знаю, как сделать эту пересылку. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете.

Comment: приведите пример вашего кода

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1154160/234134